# How to create validation rule for a custom cell with multiple textfields in swift Eureka Form?

Tags: swift, forms, uitableview, validation, netflix-eureka

I created a form using the swift library Eureka. Also I created a custom row with cell having 3 textfields arranged in a row. Before submitting the form to server, I need to check whether the user has entered values in all the three values.
How can I use the Rule for executing this ?

The custom cell class is

```
class TicketStatusCell: Cell<String>, CellType {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var partNameField : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var partNumberField : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var quantityField : UITextField!
    

    required public init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
       
    open override func setup() {
            height = {
                return 50
            }
        self.selectionStyle = .none
        
        partNameField.placeholder = " Name"
        partNumberField.placeholder = "Number"
        quantityField.placeholder = "qty"
    }

}

final class TicketStatusRow : Row<TicketStatusCell>, RowType{
    required init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        cellProvider = CellProvider<TicketStatusCell>(nibName: "iCMSTicketStatusUpdateCell")
    }
}
```

[image: The cell will be like this]

I need to change the background color of field if they are empty on submit button click

Comment: you can use https://github.com/amitcse6/ASValidator                                          validator?.invalidDisableViews([submitButton])

Comment: @ AMIT  Instead of using another library, I am looking forward to implement he validation with the validation rules available in Eureka itself.